# Does Android Virtual Device SD Card size consumes computer's HD space?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am learning from the online tutorial to create a new Android Virtual Device. There isn't much written for the settings of the AVD.

**Question 1)** If I set the SD Card size to (say 2GB), does it literally "eats up" my computer's Harddisk space of 2GB by creating an image file of 2GB?

**Question 2)** If it does takes up my computer's HD space, in future when I create multiple AVDs, it will requires a lot of HD space am I right?

**EDIT:** So when I delete the created AVDs, does it free up my HD space immediately, or do I need to do a series of thing to do a "clean" AVD deletion?

Sorry for the addition question. Thank you for all your replies. I will undoubtedly vote up all your constructive solutions by tomorrow.

Comment: Good question and unfortunately I've not given a thought to this point till now. I would like to see the response from SO else...let me dig in to get back to you.

Comment: @RamakishnaBalla Thank you so much. That's very kind of you. :-)

Comment: I suggest you use this emulator its better than Android official `AVD`  http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the harddisk space is immediately allocated.

```
# First, I created a new AVD device called 2gb-sdcard and an AVD
# device called no-sdcard (which uses the minimum size of 10MB)
# Both are same device type, SDK, skin, etc.
#
$ cd ~/.android/avd/2gb-sdcard.avd
$ du -h
2.4G    .

$ cd ~/.android/avd/no-sdcard.avd
$ du -h
410M    .
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the same even in Windows. I've Win7-64 and Confirm that the SDCard sizes mentioned for individual AVDs does occupy the hard disk space.

For e.g. I've created AVD NexusS_AVD19 with 100MB SD Card size and I've shown in the screen shot, the memory occupation.

Similarly I've created other AVDs with 1GB and 2GB SDCard sizes and similar details were available when I go to the respective path like : for e.g: `C:\Users\RAMA\.android\avd\2GBSDcard.avd` 
and `C:\Users\RAMA\.android\avd\1GBSDcard.avd`...i could see the occupation.

In case, if you want single SDCard Image to be used for all the AVDs available to use your memory efficiently / smartly, please follow this link which guides you the steps to go through to achieve this with single SDCard Image

[how-to-create-a-new-virtual-sd-card-in-emulator-in-android](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/13/how-to-create-a-new-virtual-sd-card-in-emulator-in-android/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Emulator uses .iso disk images to emulate SD card. So SD card consumes that space which you specified.

But in case you need a lot of emulators you can use for all of them a single image. Check this [Loading an SD card image](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#sdcard-loading)